# How small can the average dihedral angle be in a large polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Given a non-degenerate non-self-intersecting polyhedron $P$, consider the average of the dihedral angles at each edge in $P$. For small polyhedra, this average can be fairly small; for instance, a regular tetrahedron has an average dihedral angle of $70.53^\circ$, and the tetrahedron with vertices at $(1,0,\epsilon),(-1,0,\epsilon),(0,1,-\epsilon),(0,-1,-\epsilon)$ has an average dihedral angle approaching $60^\circ$.

I am interested in the limiting value of this average for large polyhedra, i.e. as the number of edges, faces, and vertices go to infinity. (If any one of these measures goes to infinity, so do the others.)

By taking an $N$-gonal pyramid with the vertex extremely close to the base, one can get an average angle approaching $90^\circ$ (half the dihedral angles are negligible, half are extremely close to $180^\circ$). Is it possible to get any smaller than this in the limit?

So far as I can tell, it seems like no polyhedron of any size can have an average dihedral angle less than $60^\circ$ without being self-intersecting; a proof or counterexample to this assertion would be welcome.

Comment: I am afraid that the very meaning of "average dihedral angle" is lying on sand as one can create for example 1000 new tiny dihedral angles out of an old one...

Comment: @JeanMarie: How do you propose to do this? Given two faces, the associated planes intersect in a single line, so they can form at most one edge between them if the polyhedron is not degenerate. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Imagine curving a little the old edge and dividing it into as many segments as you like...

Comment: @JeanMarie: But a curved edge cannot be the meeting point of two planar faces - planes only intersect along a unique line. Try generating an explicit example of such a polyhedron and I think you will find that the curving of an edge splits one face into many, producing lots of new edges with very large dihedral angles.

Comment: I was thingking to the "flattened" pyramid you gave as an example in your last paragraph : in this case there are also very small dihedral angles. But I agree that it does not make a significant advance on your question...

Comment: You are not restricting to convex polyhedra, right?

Comment: @M.Winter No, although if the answer is different in the convex case I’d be curious about that as well.

Comment: Without having performed any computations to check this, what about the following idea: take any tetrahedron and a vertex thereof an dent in the vertex (the vertex is now pointy towards the interior of the polyhedron, which is no longer convex). I hope you have an idea what I mean. Does this lower the average angle? You can do this to all vertices and you can also repeat the process with the same vertex again (a double dent, tripe dent etc.).

Comment: @M.Winter: I don't see a way for this construction to do better than contributing six angles approaching $0,0,0,300,300,300$, which yields $150^\circ$ on average. In general it seems hard to avoid the problem where one creates as many angles over $180^\circ$ as under it, which of course makes crossing the $90^\circ$ barrier a challenge.

Comment: A kind of opposite question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732790/how-do-dihedral-angles-grow-with-number-of-edges-in-euclidean-polyhedra/3734403#3734403

Comment: According to a formula from one of my comments there, $$\frac{\sum_e\theta_e}{\sum_e1}\geq\pi-\frac{\sum_v(2\pi-\Omega_v)}{3\sum_v1},$$ the average dihedral angle is at least $\pi/3=60^\circ$ because solid angles are positive. (At least that works for convex polyhedra.)

Comment: The same formula shows that the average dihedral angle is at least $\pi/2=90^\circ$, if the average solid angle is at least $\pi/2$.

Comment: Using the Gauss map/spherical dual (see the linked answer), your question is equivalent to this: How large can the average edge length be in a large spherical tiling? Must it be smaller than $90^\circ+\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon\to0$ as the number of tiles increases?

Comment: @mr_e_man: Thanks for the proof that dihedral angles must average at least $60^\circ$! I don't see how to conclude that the average solid angle must exceed $pi/2$ though, since e.g. a very flat cone can have arbitrarily low average solid angle.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get at least as low as $\arccos(\sqrt{5}/3)$, or about $41.8$ degrees, since that is the average dihedral angle in a great icosahedron.

Comment: I'm thinking specifically about non-self-intersecting polyhedra here, sorry if that wasn't clear - I'll edit the original post to clarify. I'm also looking at the limit for large polyhedra, so the goal is to find a construction which allows for polyhedra with arbitrarily many edges.